# Ajax registration not returning any value or error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

Ajax is not running properly for my registration form. I have a registration page called `register_process.php`.

I run through the variables from `$_POST` and echo out the variable `$error`.
I then want to use this variable and add it to the div with the id `#register_msg`. The variable `$error` will contain a `div` wrap and content.

However, I'm not receiving a error OR a success feedback from the ajax request. Neither am I getting any console errors.
How come?

**This is my Ajax Code:**

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reg_register').click(function(){
        var fullname=$("#reg_fullname").val();
        var email=$("#reg_email").val();
        var password1=$("#reg_password1").val();
        var password2=$("#reg_password2").val();
        var register=$("#reg_register").val();

        var dataString = 'fullname='+fullname+'&email='+email+'&password1='+password1+'&password2='+password2+'&register='+register;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register_process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#reg_register").val('Connecting...');
            },
            success: function(result){
                if(result){
                    $("#register_msg").html(result);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('error');
            } 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**My form**

```
<form method="post">
     Fullname:<br>
     <input type='text' name='fullname' id="reg_fullname" /><br>
     Email:<br>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="reg_email" /><br>
     Password:<br>
     <input type="password" name="password1" id="reg_password1" /><br>
     Confirm password:<br>
     <input type="password" name="password2" id="reg_password2" /><br>
     <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" id="reg_register" /> 
</form>
```

My PHP registration check:

```
$req_error = "";
$req_success = "";

/** REGISTRATION FORM **/
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    if((!empty($_POST['fullname'])) AND (!empty($_POST['email'])) AND (!empty($_POST['password1'])) AND (!empty($_POST['password2']))){
        /** FROM POST TO VARIABLE **/
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
        $password2 = $_POST['password2'];

        /** VALIDATE EMAIL **/
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $req_error .= $database_reg_6;
        }

        /** DUPLICATE EMAIL **/
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1";
        $result = $db_connect->prepare($sql);
        if($result->execute(array(':email' => $email))){
            $email_count = $result->rowCount();
            if($email_count != 0){
                $req_error .= $database_reg_7;
            }
            $result = NULL;
        }
        else{
            $req_error .= $database_reg_8;
        }

        /** CHECK FULL NAME **/
        $regex = "/^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-]+/";
        if(!preg_match($regex, $fullname)){
            $req_error .= $database_reg_9;
        }

        /** CHECK PASSWORD **/
        if($password1 !== $password2){
            $req_error .= $database_reg_10;
        }

        /** AFTER VALIDATION OF FORM **/
        if(empty($req_error)){
            $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $unique_veri = getToken(10);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (access_level, fullname, email, password, verification,registered) VALUES ('0',:fullname,:email,:password,:verification, NOW())";
            $result = $db_connect->prepare($sql);

            if($result->execute(array(':fullname' => $fullname,':email' => $email, ':password' => $password_hash, ':verification' => $unique_veri))){
                $mail_receiver  = $email;
                $mail_subject   = 'Account verification required';

                $verify_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/register?v='.$unique_veri;

                $mail_message  = 'This email contains your verification URL. Click it to confirm you are the correct owner of the account.<br>';
                $mail_message .= '<a href="'.$verify_url.'">Verification Link</a><br>';

                $mail_headers   = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'."\r\n".'From: example.no <dont-reply@example.no>'."\r\n".'Reply-To: example.no <dont-reply@example.no>'."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
                if(mail($mail_receiver, $Mail_subject, $mail_message, $mail_headers)){
                    $req_success .= $database_reg_11;
                }
                else{
                    $req_error .= $database_reg_12;
                }
            }
            else{
                $req_error .= $database_reg_13;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $req_error .= $database_reg_14;
    }
}
if(!empty($req_error)) {
    echo '<div id="register-msg-e">';
    echo '<div id="register-discard"><img src="/img/mobile-menu-active.png" height="15px" width="15px" alt="Discard Button"></div>';
    echo '<p>'.$req_error.'</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
elseif(!empty($req_success)){
    echo '<div id="register-msg-s">';
    echo '<div id="register-discard"><img src="/img/mobile-menu-active.png" height="15px" width="15px" alt="Discard Button"></div>';
    echo '<p>'.$req_success.'</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Your function expression on `beforeSend` has a syntax error.

Comment: @MinusFour What is wrong there?

Comment: Have you tried debugging `success` function? Maybe `result` could have no value...

Comment: @AlessioCantarella Tried `console.log(result);`, no results. Also tried `console.log("Error");` inside the success function and the error function. No feedback.

Comment: Can you post your PHP code?

Comment: Oh, just not copied the full snippet... let me check again

Comment: Check the bottom of the PHP code. I am.

Comment: Cancel the form submission and see if magically work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.
Your HTML fields are inside a FORM.
When you click "submit" button, you trigger the ajax request, that actually does its job but ALSO the form submits to itself (reloading the page) since it doesn't have an action tag, cleaning up the content of your div#register_msg , that had the PHP response of your ajax call.

Just remove the FORM tag from the HTML and everything will be fine.

Comment: How come this works then? http://www.9lessons.info/2014/07/ajax-php-login-page.html

Comment: why is it a bad advice ?

Comment: This worked. Using preventDefault() worked as well :)

Comment: @HelioGabrenha For some reason beforeSend doesn't let go of the value after load. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Cancel the default action of the button so the form will not submit.

```
$('#reg_register').click(function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    /* rest of your code */
});
```